# Putting one to many events and aligning them by event and Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, reporting

Good Day,

Tracking a process from Item's.  Each Item has an `EVENT_ID` when started. When an `EVENT_ID` is started there are several `EVENT_TYPE`'s
   that the Item can go through. An Item may have several `EVENT_ID`'s, some within the same day.

I want to pull specific `EVENT_TYPES` for all `EVENT_ID` within a specific date range for a report.  All data is contained within two joined table, so 
   I am using a `CTE` to pull the second `EVENT_TYPE`.

For example `Item (1), EVENT_TYPE (1), DateTime(1`) is the Start of the an event.  In my `CTE` I want to match `EVENT_TYPE (2)` to `EVENT_TYPE (1)` 
   by `EVENT_ID` & `DateTime (2)` is after `DateTime(1)`.

Having problems getting the Join to work so that the output looks like below (somewhat).  Thought of trying to build a Key field but nothing seems to work for what I can think of.  Thank you for any assistance in this matter.

```
MainRowNum  EVENT_ID    EVENT_NAME  MainStart_Time  Event(2) Row    Event_ID(2) DisplayNm(2)    EventType(2)    Event(2) StartTime
1   6958402 Event Start 4/25/16 13:26                   
1   6979578 Event Start 4/26/16 6:35                    
2   6979578 Event Start 4/26/16 6:43    1   6979578 After Event Start   56201   4/26/16 9:47
2   6979578 Event Start 4/26/16 6:43    2   6979578 After Event Start   56201   4/26/16 10:50
2   6979578 Event Start 4/26/16 6:43    3   6979578 After Event Start   56201   4/26/16 10:57
2   6979578 Event Start 4/26/16 6:43    4   6979578 After Event Start   56201   4/26/16 11:04
```

Comment: You mentioned a join on two tables. Can you provide your table layout?

Comment: Main Start - MainRowNum EVENT_ID EVENT_NAME Code_Time
1 6958402 Code Start 4/25/16 13:26
1 6979578 Code Start 4/26/16 6:35
2 6979578 Code Start 4/26/16 6:43
Event(2) Start Event(2) Row Event_ID(2) DisplayNm(2) EventType(2) Event(2) StartTime
1 6979578 CPR Started 56201 4/26/16 9:47
2 6979578 CPR Started 56201 4/26/16 10:50
3 6979578 CPR Started 56201 4/26/16 10:57
4 6979578 CPR Started 56201 4/26/16 11:04

Comment: Thanks Mark but we are looking for something more like:

`Table 1`:
`EVENT_ID INT`,
`EVENT_NAME VARCHAR(38)`,
`Table2`:
`Code Start DATETIME`
etc...

Comment: Sorry to be tardy in responding. Very busy week!  I hope this is what you are looking for:

Comment: MainRowNum     Did a (Select ROE_NUM() Over PARTION BY. Event_ID Order By MainStart_Time ) to get this 
EVENT_ID  VARCHAR (18)
EVENT_NAME  VARCHAR (100) 
MainStart_Time DATETIME

Event(2) Row (Select ROE_NUM() Over PARTION BY. Event_ID(2) Order By Event(2) StartTime ) 
Event_ID(2)  VARCHAR (18)
DisplayNm(2) VARCHAR (100) 
EventType(2) VARCHAR (18) 
Event(2) StartTime  DATETIME